# Person who dies on Ekadashi, never goes to hell?

Tags: vishnu, death, ekadashi

I heard if any person dies on Ekadashi then he never gets any kind of suffering in afterlife. Normally yamduta (workers of God of death) comes to get soul but on Ekadashi day yamdutas are forbidden to take any soul with them. On ekadashi Dharmaraja (instead of yamduta) himself comes to take soul.

So is dying on Ekadashi (Lord Vishnu's day) really that beneficial? Is it true that Lord Vishnu never let anyone go to hell if he gets death on Ekadashi?

Comment: No it's not true. It's a false assumption. It totally depends on your karma.

Comment: @thelittlenaruto Or may be it is result of their karma that he/she got chance to get death on Ekadashi.

Comment: Indeed! That's what I meant. @Rishabh

Comment: The following website (https://www.oursubhakaryam.com/mruti_death_marana_day_dosham.html) says that if death occurs on Ekadashi then it constitutes Marana Dosham. So its not that good. Wonder which scripture says that. @Vishvam

Answer (score 6):

The Ekadashi day you are referring to is known by the name **[Mokshada Ekadashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mokshada_Ekadashi)** (This day is also celebrated as Gita Jayanti – the day on which Lord Krishna gave the hold sermon of the Bhagavad Gita to Arjuna before the beginning of the Mahabharata War.) celebrated on the 11th lunar day (Ekadashi Tithi) of the Shukla Paksha (waxing moon phase) in the Hindu Calendar month Margashirsha.

> As the name itself indicates, Mokshada Ekadashi is a highly auspicious
>   day dedicated to worship of Lord Vishnu - Shri Hari to get rid of all
>   your sins and to achieve moksha or liberation after death.

The store behind the Mokshada Ekadashi or Vrat Katha can be read here on [ekadashivrat](http://ekadashivrat.com/mokshada-ekadashi/95/) in details.

Like most ekadashis, the rites involve worship and prayers to Vishnu. On this day, the avatar Krishna is also worshipped. Devotees properly observing the fast are believed to attain moksha after death.

Comment: Nice info but didn't get answer of my question.

Answer (score 3):

The Vedic doctrine of karma is the bedrock of the superstructure of the Sanatan Vedic Dharma. The Vedas and the Dharma Shastras clearly point out that sin is not washed away by any means. One has to reap the rewards or suffer the pain of acts performed.

The **Manusmriti** says

> Ekah Prajaayante Jantu Eka Eva Praleeyate; Eko'nabhunkte Sukritam Eka Eva Cha Duskritam.
>
> one is born single, he dies single, and single he reaps the reward or suffer the pain he merits.

The **Garuda Purana** adds

> Avashyameva Bhoktavyam Karma kritam Subhaashubham.
>
> surely one gets the fruits of his shubh good and ashubh bad deeds.

The stories about ekadashi vrats etc are not the authority; the truth. They have been made to inspire man to follow the right path but the Law of Karma is the truth.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE! "The Vedas and the Dharma Shastras clearly point out" - it's too broad..can you please point out reference to a specific section of a scripture so that it can be checked by others...

Comment: Sins can be washed away with devotion. Lord Vishnu use to washed away all sins of his true devotee and grant him/her libration (Said by Krishna in Geeta). Ekadashi fasts is an excellent and easy way to wash all our sins. It is stated in Ekadashi Vrata Katha that this fasts use to remove all sins and grants moksha.

Comment: "Indra, sullied by the sin consequent upon slaying a Brahmana, was again purified by celebrating a horse sacrifice" - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27808/12304

Comment: @YDS This can be argued. I mean how come sacrificing a horse can purify your sins. IMHO it'll add more sins to your buckets. We should not blindly believe on anything written in script.