# What happens if someone dies in shukla paksha dwadashi?

Tags: astrology, death

What happens if someone dies in
shukla paksha dwadashi?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The following website says death on Dwadashis not that good ... https://www.oursubhakaryam.com/mruti_death_marana_day_dosham.html

Comment: [Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28076/person-who-dies-on-ekadashi-never-goes-to-hell) is a related question.