# What was the caste of Ravana?

Tags: ramayana, ravana, caste

What is the caste of Ravana since we know the castes of Rama and others, so what is the caste of Ravana especially since he's a demon?

Comment: Ravana was a Brahmin .. Upon killing him Rama got the Dosha of killing a Brahmin which he need to get rid off.

Comment: See -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26866/4732

Comment: @Rickross thanks!

Comment: the 4 varnas exist in all jatis - devas have brahmin/kshatriya/vaishya/shudra. asuras have 4 varnas, rakhsasas have it, even animals have it.